# Repeating for until reaching a exact value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so let's say I have two equal arrays

```
var arrayData=[800,802,804,806]
var arrayLabels=['11/10/2018','12/10/2018','13/10/2018','14/10/2018']
```

How could I create a loop that stops once `arrayData` reaches 1000 and `console.log` the `arrayLabel` that it got to?

Basically, I want to know on which date I will get to a certain value.

I can't think of anything without ending in a forever loop.

Thank you!

Comment: Show us the loop you have so far

Comment: `arrayData` is consist of incremental numbers? and `arrayLabels` is always equal to `arrayData`?

Comment: both are fixed values, not changing or incrementing. arrayLabels length is equal to arrayData's length

Comment: How does `arrayData` reach 1000 if it is fixed and not changing/incrementing?

Comment: So if you have numbers from 0 to 1000, you have two arrays containing each 500 elements? That's a waste of memory. A bit of logic and you don't need arrays at all.

Answer (score 2):

So, arrays are connected by index?

Value 802 in arrayData should return '12/10/2018' from arrayLabels?

If that's a case:

```
const index = arrayData.indexOf(1000);
if(index !== -1) console.log(arrayLabels[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to know what the date will be 'at 1000', you can just offset the date at 800, with the difference between it and 1000 divided by 2. This is effectively giving you the numbers of days away you can expect the date at 1000 to be.

```js
const arrayData = [ 800, 802, 804, 806 ]
const arrayLabels = [ '11/10/2018', '12/10/2018', '13/10/2018', '14/10/2018' ]

function dateAt(number) {
  const diff = number - 800
  const date = new Date('2018-10-11')
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + diff / 2)
  return date
}

function numberFor(dateString) {
  const date = dateString.split('/').reverse().join('-')
  const diff = new Date(date) - new Date('2018-10-11')
  return 800 + diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * 2
}

const dates = arrayData.map(n => dateAt(n))
const numbers = arrayLabels.map(d => numberFor(d))

console.log({ dates, numbers })
console.log(`Date @ 1000 = ${dateAt(1000).toString()}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the arrays, you don't need them.

Let's say your `start_number = 699`, and your `start_date = 11\11\2018`.

Calculate the difference between `start_number` and `1000`, in this case `diff = 301`.

If your `steps = 2`, you know after `( diff / steps ) = 150.5` you reach `1000`. Round that up to 151 (you want equal or greater than 1000).

Then parse the date and add 151 days.

So...

```
var start_number = 699,
    end = 1000,
    steps = 2,
    start_date = '11\11\2018',
    diff = Math.ceil ( (end - start_number) /  steps) ),
    date = new Date(start_date);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + diff);
```

And there you have your date... 11th of april 2019

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmsLuatd/)